# Ajax popup redirects to home page after clicking on "add to cart"

Tags: magento2, redirect, ajaxaddtocart

When the add to cart button is clicked, the page is redirected to the home page, and I would like to stay on the current page. I have tried different ways but couldn't accomplish it or getting an error:

```
public function execute()
    {
        if (!$this->ajaxHelper->isEnabled()) {
            return parent::execute();
        }

        if (!$this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('catalog/product/', ['_current' => true])
        }

        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        try {
            if (array_key_exists('qty', $params)) {
                $filter = $this->localizedToNormalized;
                $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
            }

            $product = $this->initProduct();

            /**
             * Check product availability
             */
            if (!$product) {
                return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('/');
            }

            $data = [
                'status' => true,
                'added' => false,
                'messages' => []
            ];

            $result = $this->dataObjectFactory->create()->setData($data);

            $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                'magepow_ajaxcart_add_before',
                ['product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'result' => $result]
            );

            if (!$result->getData('status') && empty($messages)) {
                return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('/');
            }

            $this->processAddProduct($result, $product, $params);
            $this->cart->save();

            $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                'checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
                ['product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse()]
            );

            $resultItem = $product->getTypeId() == \Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped::TYPE_CODE ?
                                $this->dataObjectFactory->create()->setProduct($product)
                                : $this->registry->registry('last_added_quote_item');
            return $this->returnResult($resultItem, $this->relatedAdded);
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addNoticeMessage(
                $this->escaper->escapeHtml($e->getMessage())
            );

            $result = [];
            $productId = $this->getProductId();
            $result['error'] = true;
            $result['error_info'] = $e->getMessage();
            $result['id'] = $productId;
            $result['url'] = $this->escaper->escapeUrl(
                $this->urlInterface->getUrl('ajaxcart/index/view', ['id' => $productId])
            );
            $result['view'] = true;
            // $qty = isset($params['qty']) ? $params['qty'] : 1;
            // $stockQty = $product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem()->getQty();
            if( ($product->getTypeId() == 'simple' && !$product->getData('has_options')) || $this->getRequest()->getPost('related_product') ) {
                $result['view'] = false;
            }
            $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
            $resultJson->setData($result);
            return $resultJson;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage(
                $e,
                __('We can\'t add this item to your shopping cart right now.')
            );
            $this->loggerInterface->critical($e);

            $result = [];
            $result['error'] = true;

            $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
            $resultJson->setData($result);
            return $resultJson;
        }
    }
```